# working with maths in php trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, math

EDIT 2: See below. If this can be achieved with either javascript or jquery I'm willing to go that route.

I'm working on a project and all going swimmingly so far until I hit the maths wall.

At the moment we work this out by hand by reverse engineering from a number we already know the answer too (2114) but with each of us working it out slightly different and it taking quite awhile sometimes as none of us are very good with a calculator we always end up if slightly different results. Hence the need for something that works it out. And adding it to our intranet.

Any help working this out would be awesome. thanks.

<strike>Rules;</strike>

Get Number(gap) Between 590 -> 4500

Work out the sizes of Panel & Infills required to fill this gap with the below rules;

Panels must = odd number

Infills (if required) must = even number & be no more than 1 higher in quantity than Panels

Minumum Size for Panels = 590
Max Size for Panels = 705

Minimum Size for Infills = 75
Max Size for Infills = 175

Below is what I have so far, It's my 13th attempt.

EDIT: This code "works to a point" but the bigger the (gap) gets the more lost and confused i get and the longer and seemingly redundant the code gets. I feel like there's an equation that could do it in 2 lines but here i am writing a few hundred lines that just goes back and forth and in the end missing something or just plain old wrong. And yes all it needs to do it fill a gap with as few panels and infills as possible (within the size guides).

```
$max_size = 705;

$min_size = 590;

$panel_qty = 3;
$infill_qty = 0;

$infills_max = 150;
$infills_min = 50;

$cut_off = 0;

$gremain = 0;


// devide by panels #

$gap = $new_width / $panel_qty;

// check if gap too big
    if ($gap > $max_size) {

        $infill_qty = 2;

        // get difference between gap and max_size
        $gremain = ($panel_qty * ($gap - $max_size)) / $infill_qty;

            // makesure gremain is higher then infills min
            if ($gremain < $infills_min) {
                //cut off from panels

                $gremain_total = $gremain * 2;

                $cut_off = $gremain_total / 6;

                $small_cut_off = $cut_off;
                $large_cut_off = $cut_off;

                if ($cut_off < 10) {
                    $small_cut_off = 0;
                    $large_cut_off = $gremain_total / 2;
                }

                $infill_qty = 0;

            } elseif ($gremain > $infills_max) {
                // more infills

                $infill_qty = 4;

                $gremain = ($panel_qty * ($gap - $max_size)) / $infill_qty;

                    if ($gremain < $infills_min) {
                    //cut off from panels

                        $down_size = ($gremain * 4) - ($infills_min * 2);

                        $gremain_total = $down_size * 2;

                        $cut_off = $gremain_total / 6;

                        $small_cut_off = $cut_off;
                        $large_cut_off = $cut_off;

                        if ($cut_off < 10) {
                            $small_cut_off = 0;
                            $large_cut_off = $gremain_total / 2;
                        }

                        $gremain = $down_size / 2;

                        $infill_qty = 2;

                    } elseif ($gremain > $infills_max){


                        if ($gremain < 410) {

                            // cut off panels

                            $gremain_total = $gremain * 2;

                            $cut_off = $gremain_total / 6;

                            $small_cut_off = $cut_off;
                            $large_cut_off = $cut_off;

                            if ($cut_off < 10) {
                                $small_cut_off = 0;
                                $large_cut_off = $gremain_total / 2;
                            } 

                        } elseif ($gremain > 410) {
                            // more panels
                        }
                    }

            }

    }


}
```

EDIT 2:
Rules;

Get Number(gap) Between 590 -> 4500

Work out the sizes of Panel & Infills required to fill this gap with the below rules;

Panels must = odd number (unless its 2, so 1, 2 ,3, 5, 7, 9)

Infills (if required) must = even number & be no more than 1 higher in quantity than Panels but not = to panel quantity unless panel quantity is 1 or 2

Minumum Size for Panels = 640 Max Size for Panels = 705

Minimum Size for Infills = 75 Max Size for Infills = 175
(there is some room to play with the infill max/min but not much)

So basically this is what I need :

```
width = panel-width * panel-quantity + infill-width * infill-quantity
```

I input a 'width' and it will output 4 values; 'panel-width, panel-quantity, infill-width, infill-quantity '

below is my current (16th) attempt, it works to a point but once the numbers start getting over 3000 or below 2000 it all seems to go horribly wrong.

```
// input - 3 for adjustment
$new_width = 2515 - 3;

$un_cut = 740;

$max_size = 705;

$min_size = 640;

$infills_max = 175;
$infills_min = 75;

$cut_off = 0;

$gremain = 0;

$small_cut_off = 0;
$large_cut_off = 0;
$d1ginw = 0;
$d1ginqty = 0;

$infill_size = 0;


// see how many max size penls fit
$gpanels = floor($new_width / $max_size);
    // make sure odd number
    if ($gpanels < 3){
        // its cool
    } elseif ($gpanels % 2 == 0){
        $gpanels = $gpanels - 1;
    }

// get remainer
$gremain = floor($new_width - ($gpanels * $max_size));

// check if panels can be cut down alone or need infills
$infill_check = floor($gremain / ($infills_max - $infills_min));

    // make sure odd number
    if ($infill_check == $gpanels){
        if ($gpanels < 3){
            // all good
        } else {
            $infill_check = $infill_check - 1;
        }
    }

    if ($infill_check > $gpanels) {
        // needs infills
    } elseif ($infill_check < $gpanels) {
        // cut panels only
        $cut_off = $gremain / ($gpanels * 2);

        // make sure cut off not too small
        if ($cut_off < 10) {
            $small_cut_off = 0;
            $large_cut_off = $gremain / 2;
        } elseif ($cut_off > 65) {
            // need infills too
            $infill_qty = 1;

            $infill_size = $gremain * $infill_qty;

                if ($infill_size > $infills_max) {

                    $infill_qty = 2;

                    $infill_size = $gremain * $infill_qty;

                        if ($infill_size > $infills_max) {

                            // check how much over




                        }

                } elseif ($infill_size < $infills_min) {

                    // get remainder
                    $left_after_infill = $gremain - ($infills_min * $infill_qty);

                    $infill_qty = 1;
                    $infill_size = $infills_min;

                    $cut_off = $left_after_infill / $gpanels;

                    if ($cut_off < 10) {
                        $small_cut_off = 0;
                        $large_cut_off = $gremain_total / 2;
                    }

                }


        }

        $small_cut_off = $cut_off; // move
        $large_cut_off = $cut_off; // move

    }


if ($infill_size == 0) {$d1ginw = $infill_size;} else {$d1ginw = $infill_size + 35;}

$d1ginqty = $infill_qty;


$d1gsmlsize = floor(($un_cut - ($max_size + 35)) / 2 + $small_cut_off);
$d1glrgsize = floor(($un_cut - ($max_size - 5)) / 2 + $large_cut_off);

$d1gsmlqty = $gpanels - 1;
$d1glrgqty = 1;
```

Comment: What are the specific problems with the code you showed us above? Which calculation isn't working as expected? The on-topic page in the [help/on-topic] says "Questions _seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]." You've shown us the assigned rules and dumped a bunch of code, but without something more specific we don't know where to look.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this problem as well. Which variables are input and which are supposed to be output? Are we just trying to fill an arbitrary gap with as many panels as possible with the least number of infills?

Comment: Variables input are the gap and end output is number of panels/infills and their sizes, but yes the end goal is just to fill the gap with panels and infills.

Comment: All panels shall have the same size? All infills shall have the same size? Given a width (`$new_width`) you want a number of panels, the panels' size, a number of infills and the infills' size s.t. `$new_width = $panel-qty * $panels_size + $infill_qty * $infills_size`? What should be a solution if `$new_width` = 706?

Comment: if $new_width = 706 then $panel_qty = 1 * $panel_size = 655 + $infill_qty = 1 * $infill_size * 50. Keeping a smaller infill size is optimal for me (no infills better) but not entirely required so long as everything is within the rules specified.